# True or False method not working

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to set a method called hasPassed() for a test score but can't seem to do it.

The error I am getting is:

> windowsformapplication1.student.HasPassed()' not all code paths return a value

This is my code:

```
public int YearMark
{
    get { return yearMark; }
    set { yearMark = value; }
}

private bool hasPassed;
public bool HasPassed()
{
    if (yearMark < 40)
    {
        hasPassed = false;
    }
    else
    {
        hasPassed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that it *may* not return a value. The code actually doesn't even *try* to return anything at all.

Comment: You should have returned a value otherwise the value of HasPassed() would be always false. Try to append the following line at the end of the void `return hasPassed;`

Comment: @SystemDown as I recall VB used to return values by assigning them to the method name.

Comment: @ZaidMasud - That is true, but `hasPassed` here is a private variable, which leads me to think that this might actually be an attempt at a getter/setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to return the `bool` value -

```
public bool HasPassed()
{
   return yearMark >= 40;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to return a value, try this:

```
public bool HasPassed()
{
    return ( yearMark >= 40 )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are an old pascal user? You need to actually return the value after you assign it to hasPassed.

You should do it this way if you like your code:

```
public bool HasPassed()
    {
        if (yearMark < 40)
        {
            hasPassed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hasPassed = true;
        }
        return hasPassed;

    }
```

Or this way if you want it simpler and keep understanding it at a first glance:

```
public bool HasPassed()
{
    if (yearMark < 40)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has a bool return value, so you need to return true or false, not just set a field called hasPassed.  Change the method to return true or return false inside your if

Answer (score 0):

The fix depends on how your intended design works. If the function `HasPassed()` is supposed to *return* the boolean value of `hasPassed`, then you need to explicitly return it in the code.

```
public bool HasPassed()
    {
        if (yearMark < 40)
        {
            hasPassed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hasPassed = true;
        }
        return hasPassed;

    }
```

But, if you intend for `HasPassed()` to just change the value of the private variable `hasPassed` and not actually return anything, you need to change the return type of the function to `void`.

```
public void HasPassed()
    {
        if (yearMark < 40)
        {
            hasPassed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hasPassed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to return anything at all as long as you check what `hasPassed` is in your calling method.

```
private bool hasPassed;
public void HasPassed()
{
    if (yearMark < 40)
    {
        hasPassed = false;
    }
    else
    {
        hasPassed = true;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    HasPassed();
    if (hasPassed)
    {
         //Do something
    }
}
```

Not how i'd go about it, but its another solution.